# Booting a custom Linux kernel from USB on Real Hardware?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bootloader, kernel

I'm an absolute beginner to compiling Linux kernel. I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/asnXWOUKhTA) and I'm now left with a bzImage containing the Custom kernel and an initrd.img containing the root directory or at least that is what I understood... So now how can I put this on a usb stick and boot it from a bios or an uefi on a real PC ? I guess it needs some kind of bootloader but how can I install a bootloader on the usb and configure it to boot the kernel ? It would help if the whole process is on windows. and thanks in advance :).

Comment: Did you compile the kernel on Windows, too?

Comment: @user1686 No, I did it on a ubuntu virtual machine. But its soo important for me that the process of putting the kernel on a usb can be done on Windows.

Comment: Well, installing the _kernel_ is possible from Windows, but what are you going to do with the rootfs (the /usr, /bin, /lib)? The initrd only has a "mini-root" that's just enough to mount the real root, it won't be enough for a fully functioning system...

Comment: @user1686 For my case, I don't really need a full blown OS. I'm just using the Linux kernel as a quick solution to make a bootable c program that's it ! So the kernel here is just a part of a project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UEFI boot, start by formatting your USB stick as FAT32.

If you enable `CONFIG_EFI_STUB` then the kernel will have its own bootloader integrated directly into the bzImage. That is, you will be able to simply run the bzImage as an `*.efi` file. For removable disks, copying it to `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` (for x64 CPUs) will make UEFI automatically boot from that file.

However, without an external boot manager, it will be difficult to pass the command line and the initrd to the kernel booted this way. (The integrated 'efistub' bootloader expects the `initrd=` parameter specifying the path of your initramfs.) You have several choices for that:

- Embed the cmdline and initrd image *into* the kernel executable, using the `CONFIG_CMDLINE` parameter (I don't know the parameter for embedding an initrd but I know it's possible).
- Download a precompiled version of an EFI boot manager, such as *systemd-boot* (which is just a single `.efi` file with no modules or special installers) and drop it into your FAT32 filesystem (at the bootx64.efi path).
- 

---

For BIOS boot, you *do* need a separate bootloader. Syslinux is a good choice. If you look up e.g. the SLAX distribution, you'll see that it comes not as a 'full' disk image, but as a simple archive to be unpacked into a FAT32-formatted stick – and among them it has Syslinux itself (ldlinux.sys) and a Windows .bat file for installing the Syslinux MBR onto the USB stick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! i tried it out on the kernel image i had but it didn't work.. on other kernels/os the methods you mentioned worked. i guess its something with my configuration of the kernel.